# Marshaller not found

Tags: scala, spray-json

Just trying out the spray-json, and it seems to be having problem finding my JsonProtocols I have setup.  I have the following dependencies:

```
"io.spray"                %   "spray-servlet" % "1.2-M8",
"io.spray"                %   "spray-routing" % "1.2-M8",
"io.spray"                %   "spray-testkit" % "1.2-M8",
"io.spray"                %   "spray-json_2.10" % "1.2.5"
```

And the following code:

`Content.scala`

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

case class Content(id:String, name: String, contentType: String, duration: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val contentFormat = jsonFormat4(Content)
}
```

I get an error on the line where I'm returning `Content` in the `complete {}` block, the error is as follows and the code is below it:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[Content]    MyService.scala line 32 Scala Problem

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import Content
import MyJsonProtocol._

class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService{

  def actorRefFactory = context

  def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}

trait MyService extends HttpService {
  val myRoute =
    path("") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
          complete {
            new Content("1234", "Some Content", "YT", 60)
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?  This is literally the spray-template code with the spray-json stuff sprinkled in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Json marshaller is in SprayJsonSupport trait, so just import it into the scope:

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
```

And with this marshaller you can remove `respondWithMediaType(application/json)` directive, cause it Json is marshaled only to `application/json` media type:

```
implicit def sprayJsonMarshaller[T](implicit writer: RootJsonWriter[T], printer: JsonPrinter = PrettyPrinter) =
  Marshaller.delegate[T, String](ContentTypes.`application/json`) { value ⇒
    val json = writer.write(value)
    printer(json)
  }
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you Alex.  I missed that crucial point in the documentation, is it up there on spray.io?